# Dystopian YA SF 1,000-floor buildings ca. 1978

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to identify an illustrated young adult SF novel I read in library around 1978. The milieu was a society inhabiting 1,000-floor buildings. Naturally, my memory confuses many aspects of this book with Silverberg's "The World Inside."

The bottom 100 floors of each building are off-limits. Naturally, our teenage heroes defeat the security measures and get to the bottom, where they of course discover some dark secret that underpins the prosperity of life in the upper levels.

Anyone know the title of this book?

Answer (score 2):

Any chance it's [High-Rise](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/12331767-high-rise) by J.G. Ballard?

The novel in question is currently being made into a film.

> *It should be noted, however, that the architect in "High-Rise" takes
> on the role of the villain. The story centers on a young doctor who
> moves into a brand new high rise that contains everything a person
> would ever need. There are swimming pools, a school, and a supermarket
> all located within the large, brutalist structure. Additionally, the
> building divides its occupants into lower, middle, and upper class in
> literal terms, as the lowest floors are meant for the lower class and
> the top floors are reserved for the upper class.*
>
> <sub><sup>['High-Rise' movie, based on the novel of the same name, headed to theaters](http://www.bdcnetwork.com/high-rise-movie-based-novel-same-name-headed-theaters)</sup></sub>

Comment: No, I'm sure that's not it. The book I'm talking about was YA with an emphasis on the Y. It had teenage protagonists and some full-page illustrations, perhaps one per chapter.